# Custom ordering on calculated columns

Tags: sql-server

I have two columns which are calculated by values in another column.

```
    CASE  
    WHEN ACT.TotalScore > 850 THEN 'Cok Basarili'
    WHEN ACT.TotalScore <= 850 AND ACT.TotalScore > 700 THEN 'Basarili'
    ELSE 'Basarisiz' END as Basari,
    CASE 
    WHEN ACT.TotalScore > 850 THEN 'rgba(123,192,67,1)'
    WHEN ACT.TotalScore <= 850 AND ACT.TotalScore > 700 THEN 'rgba(253,244,152,1)'
    ELSE 'rgba(243,119,54,1)' END as Renk
```

They calculate the success and assign a color to them according to their points actually.

ON `GROUP BY` I use the same `CASE WHEN` too

Total output (with other select elements adn where clauses etc. and without order by)

```
+---------------+--------------+---------------------+
| DenetimSayisi |    Basari    |        Renk         |
+---------------+--------------+---------------------+
|            35 | Cok Basarili | rgba(123,192,67,1)  |
|            60 | Basarisiz    | rgba(243,119,54,1)  |
|            29 | Basarili     | rgba(253,244,152,1) |
+---------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

I want to make a custom order by according to 'Basari' column and tried this

```
ORDER BY  CASE 
    WHEN ACT.TotalScore > 850 THEN 2
    WHEN ACT.TotalScore <= 850 AND ACT.TotalScore > 700 THEN 1
    ELSE 3 END
```

Gives this error

```
Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
Column "Activity.TotalScore" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
Column "Activity.TotalScore" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
Column "Activity.TotalScore" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

I don't know what else I can try or how can I solve this.

Comment: Can you show all your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate your order in an subquery and order outside of that.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CASE  
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore > 850 THEN 'Cok Basarili'
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore <= 850 AND ACT.TotalScore > 700 THEN 'Basarili'
        ELSE 'Basarisiz' END as Basari,
        CASE 
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore > 850 THEN 'rgba(123,192,67,1)'
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore <= 850 AND ACT.TotalScore > 700 THEN 'rgba(253,244,152,1)'
        ELSE 'rgba(243,119,54,1)' END as Renk

        OrderByField=CASE 
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore > 850 THEN 2
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore <= 850 AND ACT.TotalScore > 700 THEN 1
        ELSE 3 END 
    FROM
        Table
)
AS A
ORDER BY 
    A.OrderByField
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your new numbering logic in the group by as well.  Make a new column and order by it.

```
   SELECT DenetimSayisi
    , CASE 
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore > 850
            THEN 'Cok Basarili'
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore <= 850
            AND ACT.TotalScore > 700
            THEN 'Basarili'
        ELSE 'Basarisiz'
        END AS Basari
    , CASE 
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore > 850
            THEN 'rgba(123,192,67,1)'
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore <= 850
            AND ACT.TotalScore > 700
            THEN 'rgba(253,244,152,1)'
        ELSE 'rgba(243,119,54,1)'
        END AS Renk
    , CASE 
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore > 850
            THEN 2
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore <= 850
            AND ACT.TotalScore > 700
            THEN 1
        ELSE 3
        END AS newColumn
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore > 850
            THEN 2
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore <= 850
            AND ACT.TotalScore > 700
            THEN 1
        ELSE 3
        END
```

If you do not want to actually query the new ordering column, you can use a CTE to drop it.

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT DenetimSayisi
    , CASE 
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore > 850
            THEN 'Cok Basarili'
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore <= 850
            AND ACT.TotalScore > 700
            THEN 'Basarili'
        ELSE 'Basarisiz'
        END AS Basari
    , CASE 
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore > 850
            THEN 'rgba(123,192,67,1)'
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore <= 850
            AND ACT.TotalScore > 700
            THEN 'rgba(253,244,152,1)'
        ELSE 'rgba(243,119,54,1)'
        END AS Renk
    , CASE 
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore > 850
            THEN 2
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore <= 850
            AND ACT.TotalScore > 700
            THEN 1
        ELSE 3
        END AS newColumn
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore > 850
            THEN 2
        WHEN ACT.TotalScore <= 850
            AND ACT.TotalScore > 700
            THEN 1
        ELSE 3
        END
)
Select DenetimSayisi, basari, renk from cte
```